# Windows Store Apps BackgroundDownloader working example

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I already check at MSDN and could not find a working example for this class.

In my windows store app I would like to download multiple files at background. I see there is BackgroundDownloader class and CreateDownloadAsync function but I could not figure out what requestBodyStream parameter is used for. Here is my sample code with throwing requestBodyStream parameter is null Exception. I tried to initialize with InputStreamOverStream and FileInput stream but both gives "The type 'Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOverStream' has no constructors defined   " error.

Am I missing something?

```
string downloadUrl = videoInfo.DownloadUrl;
BackgroundDownloader backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
Uri uri = new Uri(downloadUrl);
Windows.Storage.IStorageFile resultFile = null;
Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream requestBodyStream = null;
IAsyncOperation<DownloadOperation> asyncOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownloadAsync(uri, resultFile, requestBodyStream);
asyncOperation.Completed += delegate(IAsyncOperation<DownloadOperation> info, AsyncStatus status)
{
DownloadOperation downloadOperation = info.GetResults();

};
```

Comment: Search for  the background transfer sample.

Comment: You probably only need CreateDownload, not CreateDownloadAsync.